# Negative lookup preg_match_all in PHP for IMG tags without ALT attribute

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match-all, regex-negation

I'm trying to find the `img` tags which don't contain `alt` attribute, so to fix it for W3C validation.

I'm trying to use negative look-around syntax:

```
preg_match_all('@<img[^>]*?(?!alt=)[^>]*>@', $text, $matches);
```

which unfortunately doesn't return anything, while there are `img` tags without `alt` attribute for sure.

I thought the problem is in negative lookup, but for example I used:

```
preg_match_all('@<img[^>]+?http:\/\/(?!mysite\.com)[^>]*?>@', $text, $matches);
```

to search for images from external resources and it worked fine.

Any ideas what's wrong with the first expression?
Thanks!

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: I would never use simple_html_dom in production environment as it has memory leakages. That's why I refused from it a while ago and use nokogiri now. It really depends whether to use regex for this or not, for my purposes I think it would fit fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I found the working solution:

```
preg_match_all('@<img(?:(?!alt=).)*?>@', $text, $matches);
```

Thanks for contribution.

Comment: Wow, I'm absolutely bewildered why this works.  Why would this work but `'@img(?!alt=).*?>@'` not work?

Comment: I don't fully understand all this stuff, but the one you provide seems to search for img tags that doesn't have alt= immediately after <img, so it returns all img tags for me. But the expression, which I provided seems to search for alt attribute anywhere between open '<img' and closing '>'.

Answer (score 1):

Using the look-ahead syntax works with that first one

```
preg_match_all('@<img[^>]*?(?=alt=)[^>]*>@', $text, $matches);
```

$matches here will contain only img's with alt's.

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOF
<html>
  <body>
    hello
    <img src="withalt" alt="hi"/>asdf
    <img src="noalt" />
    <img src="withalt2" alt="blah" />
  </body>
</html>
EOF;

if (preg_match_all('@<img[^>]*?(?=alt=)[^>]*>@', $str, $matches)) {
   echo "matches\n";
   print_r($matches);
}

?>
```

Comment: this still doesn't return anything. Is it working on your side? Also as far as I understand you use positive look-ahead, but the idea was to find those tags which doesn't contain alt attribute, so I used negative look-ahead (?!).

Comment: Just made an edit with working code, of course I forgot that you wanted lines that didn't contain alt so hang on a minute and i'll see what i can come up with